# How do you get the weather module to recognise SVG files?

Tags: theming

How do you get the weather module to recognise SVG files?

I have my SVGs in: `/sites/default/files/icons/svg`

They are named correctly: 01d.svg, 01m.svg ...etc.

and that is where I am pointing to (`icons/svg`) from: `admin/config/user-interface/weather`.

PNGs work fine, but when I switch to SVGs the display falls back to the default icon set?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to, but I hacked the module: weather_theme.inc. I altered:

```
$image = $custom_path . $symbol . '.svg';
```

Here's the full function:

```
/**
 * Returns the <img> tag for the weather image to use for the current condition.
 * 
 * @param $symbol
 *   The weather condition number from yr.no
 * @param $condition
 *   The translated condition text.
 * 
 * @return $string
 *   Ready formatted HTML <img> tag
 */
function weather_format_image($symbol, $condition) {
  // Support a custom image directory. If the variable is not set or the specified
  // file is not available, fall back to the default images of the module.
  $custom_path = file_default_scheme() . '://' . variable_get('weather_image_directory', '') . '/';
  // Construct the filename
  $image = $custom_path . $symbol . '.png';
  if (!is_readable($image)) {
    $default_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'weather') . '/images/';
    $image = $default_path . $symbol . '.png';
  }
  $size = getimagesize($image);
  // Prepare the <img> tag
  return theme('image', array(
    'path' => $image,
    'width' => $size[0],
    'height' => $size[1],
    'alt' => $condition,
    'title' => $condition,
    'attributes' => array('class' => 'weather-image')
  ));
}
```